# Add event in SP2010

Tags: c#, events, sharepoint-2010, selectedindexchanged

how to add SelectedIndexChanged event for DropDownList in SharePoint2010?

Comment: Just a note - nothing here is specific to SharePoint - you'd do the same in web forms, or in any other event you need to bind dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `YourDropDownList` is the `DropDownList`:

```
YourDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(your_handling_function);
```

`your_handling_function` is the method triggered by the event:

```
public void your_handling_function(object sender, EventArgs e)
```